# spring reactive get locale in repository @Query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have localized entities in a reactive spring boot application.

The current implementation works fine by depending on the `Accept-Language` header:

**Controller**

```
@RestController
class TaskController(val taskService: TaskService) {
  @GetMapping("/tasks")
  suspend fun getTasks(locale: Locale): Map<Long?,Task> {
    return taskService.getTasks(locale).toList().associateBy(Task::id)
  }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
class TaskServiceImpl(val taskRepository : TaskRepository) : TaskService {
  override fun getTasks(locale: Locale): Flow<Task> {
    return taskRepository.findWithLocale(locale.language)
  }
```

**Repository**

```
interface TaskRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<Task, Long> {
  @Query("SELECT * FROM task t LEFT JOIN task_l10n tl10n ON tl10n.task_id=t.id WHERE tl10n.locale = :locale")
  fun findWithLocale(locale: String): Flow<Task>
}
```

### Question

As you can see, I need to pass down the `locale` from the controller to the service and then to the repository. Because a lot of our API will suffer from this noise/boilerplate I wonder if I somehow can use/inject the `locale.language` in a `@Query("... where locale = :locale")` without passing it as a parameter?

In MVC we could use `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` at least on the service level and get rid of some of the noise but it is not available in a reactive stack because it is bound to the thread and not to the coroutine.

### APPROACH

From [this spring.io post](https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/06/spring-data-2020-0-new-and-noteworthy-a-general-overview#reactive-spring-expression-language-ldquo-spel-rdquo-context-extensions) I hope to be able to setup the SpEL evaluation context in a request-aware way - i.e. to access the locale of the current request.

Something along the lines of this

```
@Query("... WHERE tl10n.locale = ?#{locale().language}"
```

But I cannot figure out these things:

1. how to put the reactive context on the SpEL context on a per request basis?
2. How to populate the reactive context with the request's locale?

### Step 1

First I found that the exchange would provide access to the locale by debugging how Spring resolves the controller method's argument: it's done in [ServerWebExchangeMethodArgumentResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/ServerWebExchangeMethodArgumentResolver.html)

```
exchange.getLocaleContext().getLocale()
```

So if I could access the `exchange` from a SpEL context, I would be happy.

```
?#{exchange.getLocaleContext().getLocale()}
```

which is not possible, because the SpEL context does not know about the reactive context:

```
Property or field 'exchange' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.Object[]' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

### Step 2

Next I figured out that I can come up with a SpEL extension holding the locale and add the extension to the reactive repositories (actually I am using kotlin coroutines based `CoroutineCrudRepository`) by using a `BeanPostProcessor` on my repositories to make my custom SpEL extension available in the `@Query("... ?#{locale()}")` methods:

````
/**
 * Adds extensions to the SpEL evaluation context.
 */
@Configuration
class RepositorySpELExtensionConfiguration {

  companion object {
    // list of provided extensions
    val contextProviderWithExtensions =
      ReactiveExtensionAwareQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider(listOf(ReactiveLocaleAwareSpELExtension.INSTANCE))
  }

  /**
   * Registers the customizer to the context to make spring aware of the bean post processor.
   */
  @Bean
  fun spELContextInRepositoriesCustomizer(): AddExtensionsToRepositoryBeanPostProcessor {
    return AddExtensionsToRepositoryBeanPostProcessor()
  }

  /**
   * Sets the [contextProviderWithExtensions] for SpEL in the [R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean]s which makes the extensions
   * usable in `@Query(...)` methods.
   */
  class AddExtensionsToRepositoryBeanPostProcessor : BeanPostProcessor {
    override fun postProcessBeforeInitialization(bean: Any, beanName: String): Any {
      if (bean is R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean<*, *, *>) {
        bean.addRepositoryFactoryCustomizer { it.setEvaluationContextProvider(contextProviderWithExtensions) }
      }
      return bean
    }
  }

  /**
   * Makes the [LocaleAwareSpELExtension] available in a reactive context.
   */
  enum class ReactiveLocaleAwareSpELExtension : ReactiveEvaluationContextExtension {
    INSTANCE;

    override fun getExtension(): Mono<out EvaluationContextExtension> {
      return Mono.just(LocaleAwareSpELExtension("en"))
    }

    override fun getExtensionId(): String {
      ReactiveQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider.DEFAULT
      return "localeAwareSpELExtension"
    }
  }

  /**
   * Provides the requests locale as SpEL extension.
   *
   * Use it like this:
   * ```
   * @Query("... WHERE locale = :#{locale()}")
   * ```
   */
  class LocaleAwareSpELExtension(private val locale: String) : EvaluationContextExtension {

    override fun getRootObject(): LocaleAwareSpELExtension {
      return this
    }

    override fun getExtensionId(): String {
      return "localeAwareSpELExtension"
    }

    @Suppress("unused") // Potentially used by `@Query(...) methods.
    fun locale(): String {
      return locale
    }
  }
}
````

**This works fine** hurray - but as you can see, I hardcoded the locale to `"en"` when creating the extension.

```
    override fun getExtension(): Mono<out EvaluationContextExtension> {
      return Mono.just(LocaleAwareSpELExtension("en"))
    }
```

When debugging this line, I know that it is executed on a per request basis, which makes me hope that I should be able to somehow use the request context to populate the locale.

### Step 3

I am stuck on how to get the request context to populate the locale in the SpEL extension as shown in step 2. This is what I try:

```
    override fun getExtension(): Mono<out EvaluationContextExtension> {
      return Mono.deferContextual { it.get<Mono<ServerWebExchange>>(ServerWebExchangeContextFilter.EXCHANGE_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE) }
        .map { it.localeContext.locale?.language ?: "en" }
        .map { LocaleAwareSpELExtension(it) }
    }
```

but the exchange is not available in the context:

```
Context does not contain key: org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerWebExchangeContextFilter.EXCHANGE_CONTEXT
```

From what I understand the context is not populated, because the Mono is not returned from the spring controller but it is used in the Query SpEL and **I guess this is not the same context chain**?

I think it must be possible, because it is similar to how the principal and security context would be made available, but I not fully understand how `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` works - especially not how exactly it is populated for the SpEL context. In fact, in my default configuration it is not even populated - again I think because it is not the same context chain. Another difference here is that spring explicitly sets the security context to the reactive context in the [`ReactorContextWebFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/fb7394c1de60a4a8e564327894d99a6f335905ad/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/server/context/ReactorContextWebFilter.java#L45).

I think I now could create my own reactive request filter to populate the locale context, but I don't know how to make the reactive context available to the SpEL context.

Comment: you can get the header in a filter and place it in the reactive context, and then pick it up from the context further down.

Comment: Could you show how to do this? I do not know how to place it in the context.

Comment: the documentation can explain this much better than me. So read that, try it out, and if you cant get it to work, update your question with what you have, what problems you get etc. And we will help you from there. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but isn't the reactor context a different context than the SpEL context? An example on how to use `ReactiveEvaluationContextProvider`  would be very helpful, because all my attempts where not showing anything different than the original problem.

Comment: I spend another day on the topic and was able to make my SpEL extension work, but still I do not understand how to populate the reactive context to the SpEL context. I made an edit to the question to show more details to all the problems and steps of my solution approach so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out adding the filter works (s. below). I still don't fully understand how the context population of SpEL VS reactive context works in this scenario, but it works..

```
@Component
class ReactorContextLocaleWebFilter : WebFilter {

  companion object {
    val KEY = ReactorContextLocaleWebFilter::class.java
  }

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
    return chain.filter(exchange).contextWrite { context: Context ->
      if (context.hasKey(KEY))
        context
      else
        withLocaleContext(context, exchange)
    }
  }

  private fun withLocaleContext(mainContext: Context, exchange: ServerWebExchange): Context {
    return mainContext
      .putAll(Mono.just(exchange.localeContext.locale?.language ?: "en").`as` { lang: Mono<String> ->
        Context.of(KEY, lang).readOnly()
      })
  }

}
```

and then adjusting the extension creation to use the web filter:

```
override fun getExtension(): Mono<out EvaluationContextExtension> {
      return Mono.deferContextual { it.get<Mono<String>>(ReactorContextLocaleWebFilter.KEY) }
        .map { LocaleAwareSpELExtension(it) }
    }
```